# Linq 'into' keyword confusion

Tags: linq

I was looking at a co-workers Linq query, shown below (the query executes correctly):

```
from ea in EquipmentApplication
join erl in EquipmentRoutingLocation on ea.EquipmentID equals erl.EquipmentID into erlWithNulls

from erlAll in erlWithNulls.DefaultIfEmpty()
join rl in RoutingLocation on erlAll.RoutingLocationID equals rl.RoutingLocationID into rlWithNulls

from rlAll in rlWithNulls.DefaultIfEmpty()
where ea.Equipment.Master_Cell.Area.Unit.UnitID == 1160
select new { ea.Equipment, ea.ApplicationFriendlyName, rlAll }
```

I'm confused as to why this works. My understanding (perhaps incorrectly) is that the 'into' keyword ends the current scope/context (and any variables created are now out of scope) and creates a new one. If this is true, why is the 'ea' variable still in scope in the last part of the query?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

When used with the `select` keyword, `into` will end the scope.
When used with the `join` keyword, `into` will add a variable containing all of the matching items from the join.  (This is called a [Group Join](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311040.aspx))

Comment: so when you use multiple joins do you use the 'into' clause and join the next query with that 'variable' that you've just added?

Answer (score 28):

"into" has two different meanings:

- In a `join` clause, it changes the translation from using `Join` to `GroupJoin`. This means that instead of getting one result per matching pair, you get one result for each element of the original sequence, and that result contains the key and all the results from the other sequence, as a group. See [`Enumerable.GroupJoin`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358101.aspx) for more details
- In a `select` or `group...by` it becomes a [query continuation](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/09/15/query-expression-syntax-continuations.aspx), effectively starting a new query with the results of the old one in a new range variable.

Comment: The link `Query continuation` is no longer valid!

Answer (score 22):

To add to what has already been said, I'd like to demonstrate the difference in the object structure produced by into versus without:

```
var q = 
    from c in categories 
    join p in products on c equals p.Category into ps 
    select new { Category = c, Products = ps };
```

Creates an object graph:

```
Category 1, Products:
  Product 1
  Product 2
Category 2, Products:
  Product 3
  Product 4
```

In this case, `q` only contains 2 items, the two categories.

Without into, you get a more traditional join that flattens the relationship by creating all possible combinations:

```
var q = 
    from c in categories 
    join p in products on c equals p.Category 
    select new { Category = c, Product = p }; 

Category 1, Product 1
Category 1, Product 2
Category 2, Product 3
Category 2, Product 4
```

Note that now `q` contains 4 items.

In response to comment:

```
var q = 
    from c in categories 
    join p in products on c equals p.Category into ps 
    select new { Category = c, Products = ps.Select(x=> x.Id) };
```

Comment: In your first example, instead of selecting the whole Product 1, 2 and 3, 4. How do you just select the IDs or Product 1, 2 and 3, 4?

Comment: @RayCheng I don't have a setup here to test, but I posted another code snippet that might work, you might need to add ToList `ps.Select( --- ).ToList()`

Comment: This is the most clear and understandable explanation so far.