# Query vs Extension Method - Using GroupBy

Tags: vb.net, linq

If I use

```
    Dim kun = From cus In customers
    Group By cus.Country
    Into Group
```

(I get an `IEnumerable.Collections.Generic.Ienumerable(of <anonymous Type>)`) on Northwind I can do the following Loop:

```
    For Each kdGroup In kun
        ListBox1.Items.Add(kdGroup.Country)
        For Each kd In kdGroup.Group
            ListBox1.Items.Add("      " & kd.CompanyName)
        Next
    Next
```

I get access to the member (`.Country` and `.CompanyName`).

But if I use the Extension Method (or Dot Notation) Syntax:

```
Dim kun = customers.GroupBy(Function(k) k.Country)
```

(I get an IEnumerable(Of System.Linq.IGrouping(of String, ... CustomerRow))) I cannot perform the loop shown above since I have no access to the members now. This is an book example so I thought it should work. Can anyone explain to me, why the DotNotation is not working here and what is wrong with this snippet?

Comment: Because they are not the same operations. `Into Group` further transforms the results. See Jon Skeet's answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3855881/linq-into-keyword-confusion

Comment: Or his blog entry here: http://blogs.msmvps.com/jonskeet/2010/09/15/query-expression-syntax-continuations/

Comment: Ah ok, that is interesting! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can still get your loops work:

```
For Each kdGroup In kun
    ListBox1.Items.Add(kdGroup.Key)
    For Each kd In kdGroup
        ListBox1.Items.Add("      " & kd.CompanyName)
    Next
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the example to show how to access `Country` and `CountryName` use `GroupBy`

```
 Sub Main
  Dim empList As New List(Of Employee)()
    empList.Add(New Employee() With _
    {.ID = 1, .FName = "John", .Age = 21, .Sex = "M"c}) 
    empList.Add(New Employee() With _
    {.ID = 2, .FName = "Mary", .Age = 25, .Sex = "F"c})
    empList.Add(New Employee() With _
    {.ID = 3, .FName = "Amber", .Age = 23, .Sex = "M"c}) 
    empList.Add(New Employee() With _
    {.ID = 4, .FName = "Kathy", .Age = 25, .Sex = "F"c})
    empList.Add(New Employee() With _
    {.ID = 5, .FName = "Lena", .Age = 27, .Sex = "F"c}) 
    empList.Add(New Employee() With _
    {.ID = 6, .FName = "Bill", .Age = 28, .Sex = "M"c})
    empList.Add(New Employee() With _
    {.ID = 7, .FName = "Celina", .Age = 27, .Sex = "F"c}) 
    empList.Add(New Employee() With _
    {.ID = 8, .FName = "John", .Age = 28, .Sex = "M"c})

Dim query = empList.GroupBy(Function(x)  New with{.Age= x.Age}) 


For Each employee In query 
         Console.WriteLine(employee.Key.Age)
         For Each kd In employee
             Console.WriteLine("      " & kd.FName)
        Next
Next employee 
End Sub


Public Class Employee 
    Private privateID As Integer
    Public Property ID() As Integer 

        Get 
            Return privateID
        End Get 

        Set(ByVal value As Integer) 
            privateID = value
        End Set 

    End Property 

    Private privateFName As String 
    Public Property FName() As String
        Get 
            Return privateFName
        End Get 

        Set(ByVal value As String) 
            privateFName = value
        End Set 
    End Property  

    Private privateAge As Integer 
    Public Property Age() As Integer
        Get 
            Return privateAge
        End Get 

        Set(ByVal value As Integer) 
            privateAge = value
        End Set 
    End Property  

    Private privateSex As Char 
    Public Property Sex() As Char
        Get 
            Return privateSex
        End Get 

        Set(ByVal value As Char) 
            privateSex = value
        End Set 
    End Property
End Class
```

Result:

```
21
      John
25
      Mary
23
      Amber
25
      Kathy
27
      Lena
28
      Bill
27
      Celina
28
      John
```

Comment: Ah ok! It is the .Key I needed. Thanks a lot! I solved my problem with:         For Each element In kun
            ListBox1.Items.Add(element.Key)
            For Each el In element
                ListBox1.Items.Add("     " & el.CompanyName)
            Next
        Next