# Left outer join using LINQ -- understanding the code

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I would be grateful if someone could explain the meaning of the term `into` while using **LINQ**. In general, I am trying to understand how to make **INNER JOIN**, **LEFT OUTER JOIN** etc. in **C#**.

I have the main table `Students` that stores a few foreign ID keys which then are substituted by their names when running a query. The names are read from look up tables such as `Marks`, `SoftwareVersions`, `Departments` etc. All fields are required but `MarkID`. The query I tried to build in **LINQ** is this:

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.Students
INNER JOIN dbo.Departments ON dbo.Students.DepartmentID=dbo.Departments.DepartmentID
INNER JOIN dbo.SoftwareVersions ON dbo.Students.SoftwareVersionID=dbo.SoftwareVersions.SoftwareVersionID
INNER JOIN dbo.Statuses ON dbo.Students.StatusID=dbo.Statuses.StatusID
LEFT JOIN dbo.Marks ON dbo.Students.MarkID=dbo.Marks.MarkID
WHERE dbo.Students.DepartmentID=17;
```

I somehow managed to get the code below worked after reading plenty of articles and watching some videos but I don't feel like I have a complete understanding of the code. The bits that confuse me are in 5th line ending with `into` and then in the very next line beginning with `from m ...`. I'm confused what `into` does and and what really happens in `from m ...`. And this is the code in LINQ:

```
var result = from st in dbContext.Students where st.DepartmentID == 17
             join d in dbContext.Departments on st.DepartmentID equals d.DepartmentID
             join sv in dbContext.SoftwareVersions on st.SoftwareVersionID equals sv.SoftwareVersionID
             join stat in dbContext.Statuses on st.StatusID equals stat.StatusID
             join m in dbContext.Marks on st.MarkID equals m.MarkID into marksGroup
             from m in marksGroup.DefaultIfEmpty()
             select new
             {
                 student = st.StudentName,
                 department = p.DepartmentName,
                 software = sv.SoftwareVersionName,
                 status = st.StatusName,
                 marked = m != null ? m.MarkName : "-- Not marked --"
             };
```

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3855926/468973

Comment: Please stick to one question per post. The two questions address entirely different aspects of working with EF. For the first question see this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15599143/861716

Comment: for some info about inner join and left outer join I recommend https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Te2o5qakvZk
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5K8jwrlKV8E

Comment: Hi thanks for the comments. I am going to edit this question and ask about the exception in different question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe **Example** section from [How to: Perform Left Outer Joins MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397895.aspx) is really well explained. Let's project it to your example. To quote first paragraph from the page

> The first step in producing a left outer join of two collections is to
>   perform an inner join by using a group join. (See How to: Perform
>   Inner Joins (C# Programming Guide) for an explanation of this
>   process.) In this example, the list of Person objects is inner-joined
>   to the list of Pet objects based on a Person object that matches
>   Pet.Owner.

So in your case, the first step is to perform an inner join of list of `Students` objects with the list of `Marks` objects based on `MarkID` in `Students` object matches `MarkID` in `Marks` object. As can be seen in the quote, inner join is being performed using [group join](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397905.aspx). If you check `Note` section in MSDN page on how to perform group join, you can see that

> Each element of the first collection appears in the result set of a
>   group join regardless of whether correlated elements are found in the
>   second collection. ***In the case where no correlated elements are found,
>   the sequence of correlated elements for that element is empty***. The
>   result selector therefore has access to every element of the first
>   collection.

What this means in the context of your example, is that by using `into` you have `group joined` results where you have all `Students` objects, and sequence of correlated elements of `Marks` objects (in case there is no matching `Marks` objects, the sequence is going to be empty).

Now let's go back to `How to: Perform Left Outer Joins MSDN page`, in particular second paragraph

> The second step is to include each element of the first (left)
>   collection in the result set even if that element has no matches in
>   the right collection. This is accomplished by calling DefaultIfEmpty
>   on each sequence of matching elements from the group join. In this
>   example, DefaultIfEmpty is called on each sequence of matching Pet
>   objects. The method returns a collection that contains a single,
>   default value if the sequence of matching Pet objects is empty for any
>   Person object, thereby ensuring that each Person object is represented
>   in the result collection.

Again, to project this to your example, `DefaultIsEmpty()` is being called on each sequence of matching `Marks` objects. As explained above, the method returns a collection that contains a single, default value if the sequence of matching `Marks` objects is empty for any `Student` object, which ensures each `Student` object will be represented in the resulting collection. As a result what you have is set of elements, that contain all `Student` objects, and matching `Marks` object, or if there is no matching `Marks` object, default value of `Marks`, which in this case is `null`.

Comment: OK. I feel I've got somewhere really close. I've understood all until (and including) `into`. It groups result per `Student`. But let's say I can have more than one mark for each student. I believe I have a structured result of a grouped join as follows: `Student1 and other fields from joins: List of 5 Marks for Student1`, `Student2 ...: null`, `Student3 ...: List of 2 marks`, etc. How is this projected into a simple SQL database table with kind of repeated records `StudentX` for all possible `Marks` for the each `StudentX`?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm not sure I understand your question. Do you want to know what sql query this ef query will generate? Also, did you check example of [grouped join](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397905.aspx), the example contains the case, when 1 element from left collection, has multiple associated elements from right collection, might be relevant to your question.

Comment: I am sorry my English is not the first language!

Comment: `marksGroup` stores collection of marks per student, or in MSDN website collection of pets per person. When I iterate over `result` from the above code, I have plain "flattened" set of rows, not structured like the result of GroupJoin. it is probably the `select` what I am confused about. Does `select` projects every possible row in this query onto new type? Thanks for the effort BTW :)

Comment: Yes it does project every possible row to the new anonymous type instance. If you want to have structure, as in `group join` example, you need to get rid of `from m in marksGroup.DefaultIfEmpty()`, and rewrite your select as `select new {..., marks = marksGroup};`, which will give you 1 student, and all the available `marks` for the student per row. If no mark exist, `marks` will be empty.

Comment: Thanks for the help. It took a while but I have finally understood it :)

Answer (score 1):

what I can say is that "into MarksGroup" stores the result data of your joined tables into a temporary (application based, not database based) resultset (in sql terms: a table, so its a `SELECT INTO`)

In the next line, your code then selects from Marksgroup the columns with your data (in sql terms: `SELECT student, department, software, status, marked FROM Marksgroup`

So basically, it's getting your data from the db, then putting it aside to "Marksgroup, and in the very next step getting Marksgroup back in your fingers to take out the data you want to use in your c# code.

Try to get rid of Marksgroup, it should be possible (haven't tested ist with your code). It should be something like this:

```
from st in dbContext.Students where st.DepartmentID == 17
             join d in dbContext.Departments on st.DepartmentID equals d.DepartmentID
             join sv in dbContext.SoftwareVersions on st.SoftwareVersionID equals sv.SoftwareVersionID
             join stat in dbContext.Statuses on st.StatusID equals stat.StatusID
             join m in dbContext.Marks on st.MarkID equals m.MarkID

             select new
             {
                 student = st.StudentName,
                 department = p.DepartmentName,
                 software = sv.SoftwareVersionName,
                 status = st.StatusName,
                 marked = m != null ? m.MarkName : "-- Not marked --"
             };
```

Your second question with 'm' : This should also show a different behaviour without your temporary resultset "Marksgroup"

Comment: Wrong. You just turned an outer join into an inner join.

Comment: @Ziko, although you accepted this answer, please note that this query may produce different results than the one you have.

Comment: Sorry, you're right, I didn't pay enough attenton to the plain SQL code