# Linq Expression: Left Join Duplicating Rows

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, linq-expressions

I'm trying to execute this Linq Expression, but the LEFT JOIN is duplicating the rows.
When I write this exactly query in SQL it works ok, but when I write it in Linq Expression the LEFT JOIN duplicates the row.
I've tried to group by.. but I've got the same result.

```
var sql = (from project in db.Project
                   join suitT in db.SuitT
                       on project.Id equals suitT.IdProject

                   join inspec in db.Inspec
                       on suitT.Id equals inspec.IdSuitT

                   join listFinalDef in db.ListFinalDef
                       on inspec.Id equals listFinalDef.IdInspec
                   into myListFinalDef
                   from groupListFinalDef in myListFinalDef.DefaultIfEmpty()

                   join artefact1 in db.Artefact
                       on groupListFinalDef.Id equals artefact1.IdListFinalDef
                   into myArtefact1
                   from groupArtefact1 in myArtefact1.DefaultIfEmpty()

                   join artefact2 in db.Artefact
                       on inspec.Id equals artefact2.IdInspec
                   into myArtefact2
                   from groupArtefact2 in myArtefact2.DefaultIfEmpty()

                   join typeArtefact in db.TypeArtefact
                       on inspec.IdTypeArtefact equals typeArtefact.Id
                   where ...
                   select new ArtefactModels
                   {
                       IdArtefact1 = groupArtefact1.Id,
                       IdArtefact2 = groupArtefact2.Id,
                       ...,
                       ...,
                       ...
                   }).ToList();
```

Whats happening: Duplicating the row
**Example**

```
Id: 1 | ProjectName: Project 1 | InspecTitle: Title 1
Id: 1 | ProjectName: Project 1 | InspecTitle: Title 1
Id: 2 | ProjectName: Project 2 | InspecTitle: Title 2
Id: 2 | ProjectName: Project 2 | InspecTitle: Title 2
```

What I'm trying to do:
**Example**

```
Id: 1 | ProjectName: Project 1 | InspecTitle: Title 1
Id: 2 | ProjectName: Project 2 | InspecTitle: Title 2
```

**EDITED:**
I'm trying to execute this SQL but with LINQ Expression:

```
SELECT art1.Id AS IdArtefact1, art2.Id AS IdArtefact2, ...
FROM
Project 
INNER JOIN SuitT ON Project.Id = SuitT.IdProject
INNER JOIN Inspec ON SuitT.Id = Inspec.IdSuitT
LEFT JOIN ListFinalDef ON Inspec.Id = ListFinalDef.IdInspec
LEFT JOIN Artefact AS art1 ON ListFinalDef.Id = art1.IdListFinalDef
LEFT JOIN Artefact AS art2 ON Inspec.Id = art2.IdInspec
INNER JOIN TypeArtefact ON Inspec.IdTypeArtefact = TypeArtefact.Id
WHERE ...
```

Comment: What sql query are you trying to write in linq?

Comment: if your data model is correct, you shouldn't have that complex `Linq` query

Comment: The short answer is use Select(your propreties).Distinct().ToList(). But judging by your query you have some issues going on with you design.

Comment: Your query seems really difficult for the simple result you need. Can you copy your models? (Calling Distinct() on the result would be easiest but that's a very bad solution of course :p )

Comment: Use the linq distinct function.

Comment: I've added the SQL Query. Could someone try to rewrite this SQL Query into Linq Expression, please? I would like to see a different way.

Comment: Can't rewrite query without seeing which navigational properties you have in your models. Isn't calling `.Distinct().ToList()` an option?

Comment: @AlexanderDerck yes, I'm.. but not working.

Comment: You can also try to use the `GroupBy` function. I'm assuming here that you want the distinct values of `IdArtefact1`: After your select, call `.GroupBy(p => p.IdArtefact1).Select(p => p.FirstOrDefault()).ToList();` I think Distinct is not working because one of the properties isn't the same for the same ID's (maybe navigational properties etc.)

Comment: Also with Groupby you won't have to take the results into memory until the call to List, with Distinct you take all the results into memory, then filter them.

Comment: @AlexanderDerck Is it possible to demonstrate to me the group by in my code? I have no idea where I put this GroupBy that you explained to me.

Comment: @Victor I posted an answer, but even if it works you should look into your code, it's weird the `Distinct` isn't working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The groupby goes like this:

```
var sql = (from project in db.Project
               join suitT in db.SuitT
                   on project.Id equals suitT.IdProject

               join inspec in db.Inspec
                   on suitT.Id equals inspec.IdSuitT

               join listFinalDef in db.ListFinalDef
                   on inspec.Id equals listFinalDef.IdInspec
               into myListFinalDef
               from groupListFinalDef in myListFinalDef.DefaultIfEmpty()

               join artefact1 in db.Artefact
                   on groupListFinalDef.Id equals artefact1.IdListFinalDef
               into myArtefact1
               from groupArtefact1 in myArtefact1.DefaultIfEmpty()

               join artefact2 in db.Artefato
                   on inspec.Id equals artefact2.IdInspec
               into myArtefact2
               from groupArtefact2 in myArtefact2.DefaultIfEmpty()

               join typeArtefact in db.TypeArtefact
                   on inspec.IdTypeArtefact equals typeArtefact.Id
               where ...
               select new ArtefactModels
               {
                   IdArtefact1 = groupArtefact1.Id,
                   IdArtefact2 = groupArtefact2.Id,
                   ...,
                   ...,
                   ...
               })
               //This will return IGroupable<key,value> with as key IdArtefact and as 
               //value an Enumerable of all the anonymous types with the same IdArtefact
               .GroupBy(a => a.IdArtefact1)
               //Select first value per IdArtefact if there's multiple
               .Select(a => a.FirstOrDefault())
               .ToList();
```

Comment: Look into this answer by the way, I think it explains why you get the duplicates, then you don't need this GroupBy workaround after all. http://stackoverflow.com/a/3855926/3410196

Comment: Thank you very much! Worked perfectly! Humm... interesting! I've tried to do with IdArtefact1 and IdArtefact2. Only worked with IdArtefact2 and I don't know why. Do you? Is it possible to put more fields to group by with this method?

Comment: Glad it worked out for you and yes, you can use an anonymous type like this: `.GroupBy(a => new { a.IdArtefact1, a.IdArtefact2 })`

Answer (score 0):

You can use my library [PowerfulExtensions](https://www.nuget.org/packages/PowerfulExtensions/). It has a `Distinct` by properties method documented [here](https://powerfulextensions.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Distinct%20based%20on%20fields%2Fproperties&referringTitle=Documentation).

Just call it at the end of the LINQ chain and pass the properties that make a row distinctive.